# maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: magento2, error

maximum call stack size exceeded error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

at legacy-build.min.js:1
at legacy-build.min.js:1
at g.h [as _each] (legacy-build.min.js:1)
at g.e [as each] (legacy-build.min.js:1)
at g.h [as pluck] (legacy-build.min.js:1)
at g.r [as values] (legacy-build.min.js:1)
at g.serializeObject (grid.js:992)
at g.registerData (grid.js:927)
at g.registerData (grid.js:930)
at g.registerData (grid.js:930)
```

Comment: This post describes what you should do in detail.=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Answer (score 0):

I have same this issue and found the cause, I've post the fix here:
[Maximum call stack size exceeded in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306379/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-in-magento2/307773#307773)