# Maximum call stack size exceeded in magento2

Tags: jquery, magento-2.2.5

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
at HTMLButtonElement.trigger (717c7c7c456e00bb8693680c02ff88c8.js:3365)
at Object.trigger (717c7c7c456e00bb8693680c02ff88c8.js:3365)
at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.js:493)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (717c7c7c456e00bb8693680c02ff88c8.js:3365)
at Function.each (717c7c7c456e00bb8693680c02ff88c8.js:3364)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (717c7c7c456e00bb8693680c02ff88c8.js:3364)
at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (717c7c7c456e00bb8693680c02ff88c8.js:3365)
at jQuery.fn.init.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as _focus]
at jQuery.fn.init.focus (717c7c7c456e00bb8693680c02ff88c8.js:3428)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.extend.focus (jquery-ui.js:57)
```

I am trying to upload images, images are successfully uploaded but on click of cancel or delete button in popup it throws above error.

Comment: This is no proper error please see the system.log error

Comment: I am not able to find any error in system.log related. Above error is seen in console

Comment: you check exception.log ??

Comment: No log in exception.log i found issue is occuring when one popup is opened on another

Comment: so it's looks like you have some kind of recurrention problem, but from the amount of code you posted I find it impossible to give you any solution.

Comment: @GosuPrzmak Let me explain u about issue i open popup of form  in which i upload file using using jquery.uploadFile,js. Later on uploading file i click on delete uploaded file ui dialog box opens up in which i click to continue delete process above mentioned error occurs. Check this http://prntscr.com/rejgt9

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this issue from my custom admin grid tab. That was I forgot to define function "getGridUrl" in my custom tab class.

```
/**
 * get grid url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/relatedPostsGrid', ['post_id' => $this->getPost()->getId()]);
}
```

With that, I had to create an admin controller corresponding with "*/*/relatedPostsGrid". This controller extends the one for my custom tab before.

```
/**
 * Save action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    $this->initPost(true);
    $result = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
    $result->getLayout()
        ->getBlock('blog.post.edit.tab.related.posts')
        ->setPostsRelated($this->getRequest()->getPost('posts_related', null));
    return $result;
}
```

and last thing to do is create a layout handle for this controller, file "*_*_relatedpostsgrid.xml"

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<container name="root" label="Root" output="1">
    <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\Tab\RelatedPosts" name="blog.post.edit.tab.related.posts"/>
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="related_posts_grid_serializer">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="grid_block" xsi:type="string">blog.post.edit.tab.related.posts</argument>
            <argument name="callback" xsi:type="string">getSelectedRelatedPosts</argument>
            <argument name="input_element_name" xsi:type="string">related_posts</argument>
            <argument name="reload_param_name" xsi:type="string">post_related_reload</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

with block `name="blog.post.edit.tab.related.posts"` exactly same the one I defined in my controller.
Missing those code the issue occurs every time I click to refresh the grid filter.
Hope this help.